# Реализация последовательности строк

Tags: python, строки, числовые-последовательности

Само задание взято отсюда
https://stepik.org/lesson/24470/step/16?unit=6776
Выведите строки, содержащие двоичную запись числа, кратного 3.

Двоичной записью числа называется его запись в двоичной системе счисления.

Данная задача очень просто может быть решена приведением строки к целому числу и проверке остатка от деления на три, но мы все же предлагаем вам решить ее, не используя приведение к числу.

```
Sample Input:

0
10010
00101
01001
Not a number
1 1
0 0
Sample Output:

0
10010
01001
```

Моё решение:

```
import sys
import re
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
```

Местный интерпретатор сайта выдает такую ошибку:
[image]

В чём дело, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что делает это "решение"? В каком месте оно проверяет кратность? В каком месте оно выводит строки, содержащие число, кратное трем?

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, это известный тип задач с простым решением: число делится нацело на 3, если разница суммы единиц в его двоичной записи на четных позициях и суммы единиц на нечетных тоже кратна 3.

Посему, можно предложить навскидку такое решение:

```
def divthree(a: str)-> bool:
    odds = sum([int(x) for x in a[::2]])
    evens = sum([int(x) for x in a[1::2]])
    diff = odds - evens
    if diff/3 == diff//3:
        return True
    return False
```

Проверяем:

```
divthree("1111") # True
divthree("1101") # False
divthree("0") # True
divthree("1") # False
```

Comment: Проблема не решается

Comment: `divthree("0") # True
divthree("0") # False` как это? )

Comment: @CrazyElf очепятка же :)

Comment: @Leonid_Kolbanov да нет, проблема решается. очевидно вы просто не знаете, как это решение применить. Из вашего кода вообще не ясно, понимаете ли вы, что делаете.

Comment: @strawdog Конечно нет